Math/Chemistry calculation (help with reasoning...)
I'm slightly confused about the reasoning behind a chemistry/math calculation, and I'll give this forum a try.

I have measured the "DPM" (disintegration per minute) from a sample. This is  related to radioactivity, and this value is equal to 1000. The value comes from radiolabeled leucine (an amino acid).

In the end, I want to calculate how much pmol radioactive matter per hour per liter I have. Thus, the first step is to convert the DPM to µl. To do that, I have made a standard curve and calculated how much DPM 1 µl is equal to. This value is 40000 dpm/ul. Thus, 1000 DPM is equal to 1000/40000 = 0.025 µl leucine.

Now I am converting this value to mol leucine. To do that, I multiply with the concentration leucine that I used in my experiment, which is 1 µM (micro molar). Doing that calculation, I get 2.5E-14 mol leucine.

This is equal to 0.025 pico mol (pmol) leucine.

Finally, to get it per hour and per liter, I divide it with 2 hours and 0.0012 l (the sample volume), and finally get 10.4 pmol leucine / h / l (rounded).


Now the math here checks out. But here's my issue that I can't let go. This is related to step 3. I used 1 µM concentration. However, I actually added 48 µl of the 1 µM of the stock concentration to a sample of 1.2 ml (or 0.0012 l). Now in step 5, I account for the volume as I divide by 0.0012, but nowhere in my calculation do I account for adding 48 µl of my sample. And I don't know if I should. If so, then where?
If I do it in step 3, i.e. multiply with 40 nM (which is the concentration equal to 48 µl of 1 µM added to 1.2 ml) rather than 1 µM, then presumably I don't have to divide with 0.0012 l in step 5, as I've already accounted for the volume this way. However, then I am not able to get the answer " per liter " as I don't have any volume unit to divide with? In addition, if I multiply with 40 nM in step 3 and skip dividing with 0.0012 in step 5, I will get a very different value, which is not that strange.
This has been bugging me for weeks and I don't know how to solve it. In the protocol I'm using, this is not explained.
I mean, if I were to add 24 µl instead of 48 µl, then I would half as much DPM, but that wouldn't be reflected in this equation.
Any help or ideas are appreciated.
